# Rotate ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid, image-rotation

I am drawing at dc (DrawingContext) of a `Grid` like this:

```
dc.DrawImage(_imageSource, new Rect(x, y, width, height);
```

But, what if I wanted to rotate the image I am drawing on drawing context?

I know I can push effect to drawing context, but, it will affect all the drawings, while I want to rotate only drawing of `_imageSource`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could push a RotateTransform before drawing the image, and immediately pop the transform after drawing.

```
var transform = new RotateTransform(...);
dc.PushTransform(transform);
dc.DrawImage(_imageSource, new Rect(x, y, width, height));
dc.Pop();
```

Alternatively you could create an ImageDrawing, add it to a DrawingGroup (which has a `Transform` property), and then draw the DrawingGroup:

```
var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
drawingGroup.Transform = new RotateTransform(...);
drawingGroup.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(_imageSource, new Rect(x, y, width, height)));
dc.DrawDrawing(drawingGroup);
```

All the DrawingContext.Draw... methods actually create and draw the appropriate Drawing objects.

---

Instead of continuously redrawing everything in an overridden OnRender() method you could also do the following:

- Create a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) as a container for your drawings. See [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx) about how to do that.
- Create a DrawingGroup with an ImageDrawing as shown above and draw the DrawingGroup *once* into the DrawingContext provided by [DrawingVisual.RenderOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.renderopen.aspx).
- Use a MatrixTransform or a TransformGroup for the complete image transformation, i.e. translation and rotation. Set the DrawingGroup.Transform property to this transform (instead of RotateTransform only as shown above).
- When an image's position or rotation angle changes, only change the related transform. Redrawing is not necessary.

Comment: I thought of this, but it has a negative effect on performance, a better solution is to have the _imageSource rotated once, rather than pushing and popping ..

Comment: As long as the image isn't moved, you could just keep the DrawingGroup. And i don't believe the negative effect on performance. Have you observed that effect, or do just fear it?

Comment: we have observed negative effect on performance when pushing and popping, yes we are moving and rotating, x& y above are not fixed

Comment: Are you doing this in an overridden OnRender() method, that gets called whenever your images change? How many image are there?

Comment: Yes, I am drawing in the overridden OnRender(), I have only two images, performance is accepted when I draw image recourses directly without transformation .. we what we have here is a graphical application, and we need two cursors to move at the same time, we can't just change the cursor, as we need two cursors, so, drawing on context was relatively accepted solution ..

Comment: Thanks Clemens, it worked, I solved it using DrawingVisual, without using and drawing context, I used TransformGroup with a translate and rotate transforms, and its fast ..